# How to define a new function contains ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot to draw the tendency of a value (the variables is called mean) over seasons. I have 2 dataframes: `a` and `t`. I want to put the chunk into a new function, so that I can supply different dataframes and x-axis,y-axis.
My pesudo code is as follows:

```
quickplot<-function(a,t,season,mean){
ggplot( )+  
    geom_line(data = a,aes(x= season,y=mean),color="red" )+
    geom_line(data = t,aes(x= season,y=mean),color="blue" )+
    geom_vline( xintercept = c(20,36,40),color= "black" ) 
}
```

Comment: Good reference for using `ggplot2` in packages (which applies here to functions as well): https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html

Comment: If you intend to call this as `quickplot(x,y,"var1","field2")`, then I'd use either `aes_string(x=season,y=mean)` or `aes(x=.data[[season]], y=.data[[mean]])`. Both should work.

Comment: BTW, it's generally more `ggplot2`-canonical to have *long* data, perhaps `bind_rows(a, t, .id=id)`, and use a single `geom_line(data=bind_rows(.), aes(x=.data[[season]], y=.data[[mean]], color=.data$id))` (plus your `geom_vline`). This way, you have a little more control over lines, and don't have to add a `geom_line` for each and every line color/type.

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?